# Waterline JS destroy model based on parent

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a schema like:

```
Question { id, user, ... }
Answer { id, user, question, ... }
```

I want to allow both user who posted answer or the parent question to delete an answer. How can I do it?

I want to remove an `Answer` if the `userId` param is either `Answer.user.id` or `Answer.question.user.id`.

The current implementation looks like

```
Answer.destroy({ id: id, user: loggedInUserId })
```

And it allows only owner of answer to remove his answer. Missing the part where poster of question can delete any answer under his question

Answer (score 0):

```
Answer.destroy({ id: id, user: loggedInUserId })
```

Will query for `Answers` that are written by the user with `loggedInUserId` and have the given `id` and will destroy the one it finds. To achieve what you are trying to do, considering that you know your answer's id, you should do something like:

```
Answer.findOne({id: answerId}).populateAll()
.exec(function(err, answer) {
   if (answer.user.id == loggedInUserId || answer.question.user == loggedInUserId) {
    answer.destroy(callback);
   }
});
```

Considering that `answer` is the `Answer` instance that you want to destroy.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is I need a `Answers.find()` first right?